# Is there an example of using NonLinearFit in Labwindows?

Tags: curve-fitting, labwindows

I want to fit a curve defined by a certain function to a set of (x,y) points.

The documentation says Labwindows features a function for this purpose, NonLinearFit.

I am wondering if anyone has an example of how this function can be used.
 I have not been able to find any examples in the documentation or anywhere online.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a NonLinearFit.  It is in the Advanced Analysis library, which may require Full-Development Kit.  If you do not have Advance Analysis, then look ***[here](http://users.ics.forth.gr/~lourakis/levmar/)*** for an open source version of the algorithm used in the CVI function.  I, unfortunately have not used the function, however the function panel arguments will give you fairly good clues on what inputs and outputs are required...

***Here is a*** ***[link](http://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/370051V-01/cvi/libref/cvinonlinearfit/)*** ***to how to use it***, fortunately giving a little more information than the function help included in the function panel.

Here is an image of the CVI version's help screen:

[image]

By the way, while you are in the CVI editor, if your file is within scope of a particular library, and you are not sure exactly how it is spelled, or cannot remember the exact name, you can place your cursor in the .c file editor and partially spell it, then press `<ctrl> P`, a popup will appear showing all the functions with names containing that partial string.  (eg. NonL`<ctrl>P`)
Like this:
[image]

Comment: @Ehsan - I am curious if this ever worked for you?  If you have access to Matlab, it may be a better fit (no pun intended) for this requirement.